# I want to remove repetative elements of an array without using any in-built methods of javascript. When remove a then with a, A also to be removed

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ascii

```
let RepeatingItemList = [3, 'a', 'a', 4, 3, 'b', 'A', 'b', 'c', 4, 6, 9, 8, 'b', 'a', 2, 6, 3];
let index = 0;
let compareIndex;
IndexLength = RepeatingItemList.length;
while (index < IndexLength) {
    compareIndex = index + 1;
    while (compareIndex < IndexLength) {
        if (RepeatingItemList[index] == RepeatingItemList[compareIndex]) {
            RepeatingItemList.splice(compareIndex, 1);

        }
        compareIndex++;
    }
    index++;
}
console.log(RepeatingItemList);
```

1. Not to use any in-built methods of javascript.
2. Remove A with all a.

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you want to complicate simple things?

Comment: This is not the correct question format for this website. Asking "is there a built in method that lets me remove repeated elements" is fine. Asking for somebody to write you a solution is not.

I suggest trying to do this yourself and if you have issues writing the function. If you get stuck then that is a good time to ask for help.

Comment: `RepeatingItemList.splice` is a built-in method. Are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object for keeoing track of the seen items and normalize them before to a lower case string.

For removing unwanted items, you could use another variable for the new length of the array, which is the target for copy the item from the actual index to a closer position to start without unwanted items. At the end adjust the length of the array.

```js
const
    remove = array => {
        const
            normalize = v => v.toString().toLowerCase(),
            seen = {};
            
        let l = 0,
            i = 0;        
        
        while (i < array.length) {
            if (!seen[normalize(array[i])]) array[l++] = array[i];
            seen[normalize(array[i])] = true;
            i++;
        }
        array.length = l;
    },
    array = [3, 'a', 'a', 4, 3, 'b', 'A', 'b', 'c', 4, 6, 9, 8, 'b', 'a', 2, 6, 3];
    
remove(array);
console.log(...array);
```